# macOS: How to bring a specific program forward with a keyboard shortcut?

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts, macos-mojave

How can I bring a specific window or program forward (and "active) with a single keyboard shortcut?

I wrote an AHK script to do this on Windows: I would hotkey a window to `Win`+`1` for example, and then whenever I pressed `Win`+`1`, I would activate that window.

I want to do the same thing in MacOS now.  I have a few frequently used Windows I would like to access deterministically: "You press X hotkey, you get Y window--every time."

Example: Slack.  Slack only has one window, so it should be simple.

On Windows, I got a bit fancy because sometimes I wanted one Chrome window out of the lot, so I would make `Ctrl`+`1` "set" the currently active window to be raised whenever `Ctrl`+`1` was pressed, but for the first iteration, I just want to do single-window applications (or every window from an application--whichever is easier).

Detail: when I bring the window "forward", I want to be able to type in that window without also having to click on it.  It should be fully "active" as if I had clicked on it.

I'm aware of things like `Alt`+`Tab` and the other Apple hotkeys, but they aren't deterministic.  There's no way to press a certain keyboard combo and *always* get the same window.  I don't want to scroll through a list of my open windows or anything.  I want X app, right now, immediately.

Comment: Why don't you use Spaces? One specific app to each Space. Then it's as simple as using the built-in key-commands to bring each Space to the front & the app will come with it. See https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/179376/85275

Comment: I have a 32 inch 4k monitor. I don't need that whole space for, for example, Slack (when Slack's thread view is fixed width).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a method that works (for all windows for a specific program).

1. Create an AppleScript as follows (e.g., in `/Users/<username>/activate_chrome.scpt`:

```
tell application "Google Chrome"
    reopen
    activate
end tell
```

2. Grab https://github.com/deseven/icanhazshortcut (I'm currently running `1.1.0`)
3. Create the shortcut of your choice and point it to run `osascript /Users/<username>/activate_chrome.scpt`

I tried the same thing in the Automator app, but the there were a lot of permissions issues and it would only activate the shortcuts when I had certain apps active and not others.

Comment: do you know anything more about https://github.com/deseven/icanhazshortcut running on Catalina...b/c I got it installed ok with HomeBrew, but I cannot get it to run b/c I get the "App can’t be opened because Apple can’t check it for malicious software"

Comment: @FlakDiNenno it's been a spell. you can bypass the Apple security by command right clicking on the app, select open, then hit open in the dialogue that shows.

Answer (score 1):

I made an open-source tool that does that on Windows and Linux. I **had** a working MacOS version a while ago but discontinued it because of a lack of experience in the MacOS ecosystem.

If you have the skills, please take a look at this : https://github.com/xurei/hyperkeys/

Like I said, it won't work for MacOS out of the box, but I made it work before, so I guess it's possible to have it back.

Feel free to fill in a Github issue if you need my help ;-)